# how to mix multiple video flvs into one stream?

Tags: php, video-streaming

Hi actually i want to display ads between my videos. so how to mix multiple video flvs into one stream? I am using wowza streaming server and it's rtmp protocol.

If I had a scenario where I have 2 flv files, can I build a stream, where the first flv plays for a specified number of seconds/minutes and pause then, the second one starts and completes, and the first resumes and completes?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get what you want is to solve this on the client-side by using a playlist. Most FLV players (like the common [JW FLV Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)) have options for that. Just set up your playlist like this:

1. Play first ad
2. Play main movie
3. Play last ad

Comment: yes but he wants it into a smooth stream, not paying the first video then stop to load the second and then play it and then stop to load the next one and so on... He wants like a "buffering" thing for already recorded videos...